# Play Scala template, define object vaiable

Tags: java, scala, oop, playframework

I want to define an object type variable on Play Scala template.
I already try the code below but failed

```
@import models.support.Date; var date= dateTime.getDate(0);
@date.toString() ->> failed!
```

I have DateTime class in Java that have Date and Time object
How to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a var? Scala template (Twirl) offers @defining function for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct. For example the next code from my project:

```
@import models.User.Crumb; var myUser = ViewArgsBus.getUserCrumb();
@myUser.toString()
```

Will output `models.User$Crumb@7c04315e`

**Update**

I verify method overriding as well.

Class:

```
public static class Crumb {
    public String name;
    public String url;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + ":" + url;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
@import models.User.Crumb; var myUser = ViewArgsBus.getUserCrumb();
@myUser.toString()
```

Output:

```
admin:admin
```